# How can I write this javascript loop better way

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this JS code

```
if (parseInt(counter.text(), 10) > 0) {
    counter.text(parseInt(counter.text(), 10) - 1);
}

if (parseInt(counter.text(), 10) < 1) {
    counter.attr('data-active', true);
}
```

This just checks if the count is > 0 then decrement it and if after decrementing == 0 then hide it.

I am looking for some better way to write it. I always get caught in code review about non efficient coding ;)

Comment: There is no loop in the code you posted.

Comment: Also: you're fetching the same content twice or thrice, and then passing that same content to `parseInt()` twice (or thrice). That's a very easy target in a code review.

Comment: Also: "better" is usually open-ended unless you have a specific problem. Your request seems to be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you the same behavior, without spending as much time parsing.

```
var value = parseInt(counter.text(), 10);
if(value > 0) {
    value--;
    counter.text(value);
}
if(value < 1) {
    counter.attr('data-active', true);
}
```

- Create a variable to hold the result of parsing. This reduces repetition of code, as well as avoiding doing the same work over and over.
- You were reducing the value found in `counter.text()` prior to checking the value, so I'm reducing the value of the variable to preserve the same behavior.

Note that you probably can improve the performance of your *loop* even better, but you haven't included your loop in the OP.

Comment: can i use one if loop rather than two . also i think of puting the second if inside first because the case is only if count ==1 and we decrement it then we want to hide it. if count is already zero , then i think we don't need to hide because then the element is already hidden. sorry i don't have loop . i have this in function which called to decrement the count . i only want to chk if ==0 after decrementing then we hide it as well. instead to show 0

Comment: 1: `if` is not a *loop*. It is a *branch.* 2: Yes, if you know that the counter cannot be given a negative number by any other external source, then you could safely put the second `if` block inside the first and end up with similar behavior. If that's the case, it seems like you should be checking whether `value == 0`, purely to make your intent more obvious.

Comment: you are right , this is where i get comments in CR. i am confused which condition to check

Comment: Check the condition that makes it most obvious what you are trying to do. Imagine that you're explaining to someone, in simple language, what you want your code to do. Then structure your code based on what you explained. It's an art, but if you keep working on it you can improve.